# Django sharing a lock between workers gunicorn

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views, python-multiprocessing, gunicorn

I am trying to loop inside a view function and I don’t want another worker to run the same loop.

For which i am using Lock() but i am unable to achieve this.

```
from multiprocessing import Lock
import time

lock = Lock()

def loop_func(request):
    lock.acquire()

     # loop start
     for i in range(0,100):
        print ("did work ", i)
        time.sleep(1)
     finally:
        lock.release()
```

can someone help me if there is a way where i can make the shared lock for all workers so that lock will wait till the other worker to finish and enter the loop

Comment: If you don't mind installing a new package, there's https://github.com/ionelmc/python-redis-lock . Or just make your own locking mechanism using `Redis`.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to overcome this by using [redis-lock](https://github.com/ionelmc/python-redis-lock) .

```
from redis import Redis
conn = Redis()
import redis_lock

lock = redis_lock.Lock(conn, "request_lock_adding_data")

def loop_func(request):
    lock.acquire()

     # loop start
     for i in range(0,100):
        print ("did work ", i)
        time.sleep(1)
     finally:
        lock.release()
```

Tested it with 10 parallel request it works 100%